# Snowflake Stored procedure called from ADF

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to call Snowflake stored procedure from ADF (lookup activity)that inserts the log count of all tables once it gets extracted from source/loads into snowflake. Stored procedure throws error when it is not able to insert log of a particular table in the loop but overall when it is done with process (log counts for all) it shows only success in the look up activity even when it is failed for some tables. How can I fail the pipeline in this case?

In try, I am just extracting the table details and load count and in catch I am executing below :

catch (err) {
throw `Failed to insert data change to log, error: ${err}`;

here's the code:

```
try {
    var xxxx = 
    INSERT INTO LOG.yyyy (            
        LOAD_SCHEMA,
        LOAD_TABLE,
        RAW_SCHEMA,
        RAW_TABLE,
        EXTRACT_ROW_COUNT,
        LOAD_ROW_COUNT,
        LOAD_LATEST_RECORD_ROW_COUNT,
        RAW_ROW_COUNT
    )
    SELECT
        '${LOG_TIMESTAMP}',
        IFF('${PHASE}' = 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR), '${PHASE}'),= 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR), '${EXTRACTfined', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR), '${LOAD_SCHEMA}'),
        IFF('${LOAD_TABLE}' = 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR), '${LOAD_TABLE}'),           
        IFF('${EXTRACT_ROW_COUNT}' = 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), '${EXTRACT_ROW_COUNT}'),
        IFF('${LOAD_ROW_COUNT}' = 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), '${LOAD_ROW_COUNT}'),
        IFF('${LOAD_LATEST_RECORD_ROW_COUNT}' = 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), '${LOAD_LATEST_RECORD_ROW_COUNT}'),
        IFF('${RAW_ROW_COUNT}' = 'undefined', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), '${RAW_ROW_COUNT}');`;
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: xxxx});        
    return `Succeeded`;
}
catch (err) {
    throw `Failed to insert data change to log, error: ${err}`;
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire try/catch block, and a bit more detail on the behavior you want to happen when the SP throws the error?

Comment: I have added part of my try and catch code in summary. I hope it will help to understand more.  When there is failure in getting log I do get error from stored procedure but somehow it doesn't fail ADF pipeline through which I am calling this procedure.

Comment: When you use the JavaScript `throw` method, it will generate a SQL error on Snowflake. If your ADF pipeline is looking for particular error message text, note that Snowflake wraps the error message in the `throw` with its own error message and reports a javascript error with line number. There appears to be no way to suppress that. If the ADF job is just checking for a SQL error, it's missing it because `throw` from a stored procedure definitely raises one. You can confirm this in the query history view. The call statement will be in red with an error.

Comment: We are calling sp's from Azure Data Factory. thing is stored procedure does throw the error  but ADF doesn't know an error occurred. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Throw error in an activity is currently not supported in the Azure data factory.

As a workaround, you can pass the **output** value of **lookup activity** (SP returned value) to an `If Condition` activity.

1. Add an activity to explicitly fail the pipeline (Example: Add web activity and call invalid REST API).
2. Or you can [cancel the pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/cancel) by making a REST API call to HTTP POST from a web activity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to find a solution.